# Выборка строки в HTML таблице регулярным выражением

Tags: php, html, регулярные-выражения

Есть простой код, из строки по регулярке выбираетя подстрока:

```
$str = '<tr><div class="dt"></div></tr>';

preg_match('/<tr>(.|\s)*<\/tr>/', $str, $array);

foreach ($array as $value) {
    echo $value;
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

На странице я получаю:

```
<body>
  <div class="dt"></div>
  <br>
    >
  <br>
</body>
```

Вопрос: Откуда взялась эта крыша перевернутая?

Answer (score 2):

А у меня вывел такое

```
<tr><div class="dt"></div></tr><br/>><br/>
```

Попробуйте так

```
$str = '<tr><div class="dt"></div></tr>';
preg_match('/<tr>(.*)<\/tr>/', $str, $array);
var_dump($array[1]);
```

Comment: Лучше добавить "ленивости"

    /<tr>(.*?)<\/tr>/

Answer (score 1):

Вместо `(.|\s)*` пишите `(.*)`, а то в переменную `$array[1]` приходит только последнее совпадение. А `\s` входит в  `.` .